# git rebase causes code reverted back to old commit

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have been working on a my-branch. I do git add and commit and push regularly. Before I can create a pull request, I usually do `git rebase QA` in order to rebase it based on QA branch. Today I encountered a case which I never had before. When I do `git rebase`, there were some conflicts. As usually, I resolve the conflicts, stage and commit them. However, some files, instead of showing the latest code, shows the code from my previous commits.
For example:
QA code:

```
getLeca();
        getPews();
    }, []);
```

My Branch's latest code:

```
if (specialty === VETERINARY && !selectedPet) return;
        if (specialty === DENTAL) {
            getLeca(); // Mortality score
        }
        getPews(); // economic well Being
    }, [selectedPet]);
```

My Previous commit:

```
        if (specialty === DENTAL) {
            getLeca(); // Mortality score
        }
        getPews(); // economic well Being
    }, [selectedPet]);
```

What I see during the rebase process is the previous commit. I'm not sure why this is happening.
Any insight would be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So you have:

```
[QA Branch]     A --- B --- C --- D --- E
                 \
[My Branch]       F --- G --- H
```

- **A-E** are commits on the QA branch.
- **F-H** are your commits on my-branch, with H being the latest.
- During rebase, Git tries to apply F, G, and H on top of E.

The issue comes during conflict resolution:

```
[Rebase Process]    A --- B --- C --- D --- E --- F' --- G' (?) --- H' (?)
```

- **F', G', H'** are the rebased commits.
- Conflicts are usually encountered during these rebased commits.

First... backup of your branch (`git branch backup-my-branch my-branch`)
Then do a `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --branches` to see the history of your branch and the QA branch. That helps you understand what changes are being introduced and where conflicts might occur.

I know that, when I resolve a conflict, it is not always on the latest code, since G, in this example, shows a "previous commit". After resolving conflicts, `git add` the files and then `git rebase --continue`: once the rebase is completed (check with `git status`), you should see your latest changes.